# C# ListView SelectedIndices and SelectedItems Count Issue

Tags: c#, listview, count, assembly-references

Having some trouble with these methods on C# 2010 express with **a new winform project** both data types have the method count, which seems to be documented on MSDN, however I can not seem to get them to work. The listview control itself seems fine when compiling.

```
 listView2.SelectedItems.Count();
```

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method
>   'Count' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
listView2.SelectedIndices.Count();
```

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedIndexCollection' does
>   not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedIndexCollection' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Both data types seem to be defined. Also cannot use indices.

```
 listView2.SelectedItems[0]
```

Comment: Remove the brackets `()` from the end, currently you are calling them like they are methods.  I believe they are properties.

Comment: The use of [] is correct, you do however have to make a statement out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are properties, not methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedlistviewitemcollection.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexcollection.aspx

Remove the brackets:

```
var count = listView2.SelectedItems.Count;
count = listView2.SelectedIndices.Count;
```

You can use index notation on them.  The `SelectedItems` property exposes a `string` and `int` index.  The `SelectedIndices` property only exposes an `int` index.

Answer (score 0):

You're issuing the call as if it were a method.  You're just trying to access the Count property of the list.  Remove the () at the end of your Count call.